# Regex extraction

Tags: java, regex

I want to Extract **IFNXXXXX** from the following String. Can someone help.

Open Items: P2926 some text IN204556  **IFN216441** some more text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would be regular expression, it will match IFN followed by 1 or more numbers:

```
/IFN\d+/
```

Answer (score 2):

`\b(IFN\d{6})\b` [Numbered capture group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)
 **OR**
`\b(<GroupName>IFN\d{6})\b` [Named capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

**Explanation**

- `\b` Start and end with the word boundary
- `IFN\d{6}` Character sequence IFN following by `6` digits
- `<GroupName>` Name of the capture group

Comment: I have updated the answer to add named capture group in addition to numbered capture group